# Install a virtual Windows 7 on Windows XP machine - is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is it possible to achieve? I have a Pentium Dual-Core CPU E5200 2.50GHz, 2.00 Gb RAM computer with Windows XP installed. Most of the information on virtual machines I found deals with Windows XP being installed on Windows 7 machine, while I need the reverse.

Comment: Yes it is possible but with just 2 GB of RAM you will not have a lot (if any fun) running this setup. In addition you probably won't be able to run Skype and/or Discord with video. Audio might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MS Virtual PC](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) which is well supported on XP to run Windows 7, even a virtual Windows 2012 server which I personally tested.

You'll have to remain congruent in your version, if you're using 32bit XP then you'll have to use 32bit virtual machines since a 32bit host system can't virtually expand its memory address space for a 64bit operating system.

YOU CAN, however, run 32bit virtual machines inside a 64bit XP version of Windows.